# What is stored in $ra before we perform JAL in a recursive function

Tags: function, recursion, assembly, mips, calling-convention

[image]

In the 1st iteration of this function, we may perform `recur:` and execute this line: `sw $ra, 0($sp)` which is done before any `jal` statement. From what I understand, `jal` (jump and link) statement will input into the `$ra` register, the location directly after the `jal`. So what is happening in the example if nothing is stored in `$ra` yet?

Comment: This is a function; on entry `$ra` holds the return address your caller wants you to jump back to.  A register can't hold "nothing", it's always a 32-bit value.  If some code set `$ra` to 0 or some invalid address and jumped to this function with `j` instead of `jal`, it would crash when it returned and that would be the caller's fault.

Comment: @PeterCordes so in the 1st iteration, $ra will hold some address right after a `jal` most likely in `main`?

Comment: Yes; try it in MARS or SPIM and single-step using the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a function; on entry `$ra` holds the return address your caller wants you to jump back to.

Along with having the first 4 integer args in $a0..$a3, this is part of the contract between caller and callee that is necessary for them to agree on to make function calls work.  This part of the *calling convention* is of course designed around the MIPS `jal` instruction so function call/return can be done with one instruction each.  That's also why `$31` has the symbolic name `$ra` = return address.

---

A register can't hold "nothing", it's always a 32-bit value.

If some code set `$ra` to 0 or some invalid address and jumped to this function with `j` instead of `jal`, it would crash when it returned and that would be the caller's fault.  Your function can simply assume that `$ra` holds a valid return address on function entry, whether that's from a recursive call or from some other caller.

(This is kind of the point of recursive functions, that you really are just making a function call to this function and it doesn't matter where you called from.)

---

Note that the top-level label in a program (e.g. in the MARS simulator) is *not* strictly a function.

In MARS it's common to call this label `main` despite the fact that `$ra` holds garbage or `0` at that point, so it has to exit with an exit system call; `jr $ra` would crash.

(In C, `main` is a true function that's normally reached from a `_start` entry point that sets stuff up before calling main.  In C `main` itself can be recursive without any special tricks.  If you write programs to run under a real OS, not the toy system that MARS emulates, you normally use the `_start:` label for your true entry point from the kernel, or you just write a main and link with startup code provided by the C library that calls `main`.)